# Is there a way to remove cockroaches without having to use poison?

Tags: pest-management, pesticides

My parent's house has a pretty bad case of the cockroaches currently and I'm wondering if there is an eco-friendly way to deal with them. I don't find the use of poisons appealing at all seeing as this is the room where all our food is prepared in.

Is there some sort of natural predator of cockroaches you can introduce that will get rid of them, I'm open to suggestions, I just don' want to use poisons.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=get+rid+of+cockroaches+naturally ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most insects a mixture of 1 cup water, 1 cup borax powder or welding flux, and 1 cup honey works. Dissolve the borax in water, add the honey, and mix.

Spray around edges, under the fridge etc. It is safe to use. Honey draws most insects to eat it. The borax sticks to them and perforates their shells, so that they 'bleed' to death. They also carry it back to the nest. It is slow but kills all insects that come in contact with it.

Comment: You can also do this using icing sugar (confectioners sugar) and powdered borax.  Most recipes have a higher sugar to borax ratio -- often 10 to 1.

Comment: Clean the sprayer well after use.  If it dries in the sprayer you will have fun getting it unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

Ultrasonic Pest Repellent. If you have any pet mice, then this device could be cruel. Otherwise, it's a really effective, harm-free, & eco-friendly tool.

Comment: We tried it.  The mice thought it was hilarious.  The flies chuckled to themselves in sardonic amusement.  All stayed.